¿Por qué el controlador no recibe los datos correctamente?
Tengo un error al enviar los datos del cliente con metodo POST por medio del metodo fetch.
Tengo esta funcion 'facturar' en la cual voy a enviar la información del cliente en formato JSON en la variable 'datos' para ser enviada por medio de fetch. La convierto en JSON desde el array factura['cliente'].
function facturar(factura){

    if (factura['cliente'] == null || factura['productos'] === undefined) {

        alert('Por favor verifique los datos de facturación');
    

    }else {
            //console.log(factura);
            let datos = JSON.stringify(factura['cliente']);
            
            let url="../sell";
            let encabezado = {
                             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
                            }
            let metodo = 'POST';
            
            fetch(
                
                url,{
                headers: encabezado,
                method: metodo,
                body:datos
            })
            .then(response =>  response.json())
            .then(respuesta => {
            
                console.log(respuesta);
                
            })
    }

Todo me envia normal, no tengo error en el javascript incluso la funcion store en el controlador se ejecuta normalmente pero la información no le llega al Request.
Si en la función 'store' imprimo el request con la función 'echo' de esta manera:
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        echo($request);
    }


Me muestra esto:

Me muestra un String que en la parte de abajo tiene el JSON que envie, pero como es un string no pudo manipular la informacion que necesito ya que me deberia de llegar en formato json.
Si ese mismo response lo convierto en JSON para responderle al fetch de esta  manera:
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        echo(json_encode($request));
    }

Me muestra el Request pero vacio de esta manera:
{"attributes":{},"request":{},"query":{},"server":{},"files":{},"cookies":{},"headers":{}}
Esta es la ruta que tengo habilitada en el archivo web:
Route::post('/admin/sell', [App\Http\Controllers\SellController::class, 'store'])->name('sell.store');

No creo que sea problema de la ruta porque como les digo la función 'store' se ejecuta sin problema en el controlador.
Cuando quiero imprimir el Request con print_r() sale el siguiente error:
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 260050944 bytes) in file C:\xampp\htdocs\scriptpos\app\Http\Controllers\SellController.php on line 42

no se por qué dice que tamaño de memoria en el php.ini esta el limite de memoria en512M
PD: la variable $_POST sale vacia aunque los datos se envian por ese metodo.
Por favor me ayudan el porque no llegan los datos en el formato correcto si desde el fetch se muestra que son enviados correctamente y el controlador ejecuta la funcion.

Un JSON es un string, en tu request van muchos más datos, para obtener el body debes hacer $body = $request->getContent() y para convertirlo en objeto $objeto = json_decode($body);

Hola Yarlon, diría que el problema está acá JSON.stringify(factura['cliente']);, por contexto se me ocurre es el ID del cliente, entonces, para poder recibir este dato deberías hacer algo como JSON.stringify({cliente: factura['cliente']});

@Yussef gracias ese era el detalle, en todos los ejemplos que vi era necesario hacer eso entonces nosé porque les funcionaba. Pero tu respuesta fue la correcta.

Una Request, contiene 3 elementos

Request line: Compuesto por el Method, el target (la url destinto) y la versión del HTTP
Header: Multples elementos del tipo clave/valor
Body: El contenido útil

En tu función recibes un objeto Request, que evidentemente contiene la información que te indico arriba, objeto al cual lo transformas en un string (JSON) haciendo uso de json_encode
Para obtener el body en laravel puedes usar la función getContent():
$body = $request->getContent();

El resultado en tu caso será un string con formato JSON, para convertir ese JSON en un objeto PHP debes hacer:
$objeto = json_decode($body);

